# Preserving namespaces on custom elements in Nokogiri HTML

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have sample HTML that I have marked up with some special tags that will be used by a different program, an example of the html is below.  You should note the `<START:organization>..<END>` elements.

```
<html>
<head/>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li> <START:organization> Advanced Integrated Pest Management <END> </li>
    <li> <START:organization> American Bakers Association <END> </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I wanted to use Nokogiri to preprocess the HTML to easily remove irrelevant tags like `<script>`.  I created the following extension to the Nokogiri Document class:

```
module Nokogiri
  module HTML
    class Document
      def prepare_html
        xpath("//script").remove
        to_html.remove_new_lines
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that Nokogiri is changing the `<START:organization>` element to `<organization>`.

Is there anyway that I can preserve the HTML to maintain my custom markup tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like the other two said, if your input is not standard XML nor HTML you cant really expect a parser designed for that to work.

nevertheless you could do one of the following:

1. hack up Nokogiri to work for this
   case
2. alter other program you are
   using ( curious what it is ) to
   follow standards
3. write a separate
   parser for the DSL you are using

Answer (score 1):

A long shot, but try patching Nokogiri::XML::Document and/or use `to_xml` instead - namespaces aren't valid in HTML, so I'm guessing Nokogiri doesn't parse/generate them.

Granted, your `<END>` tags aren't valid XML either, so your document is not valid in either standard.

Answer (score 1):

If your markup is valid, you could parse it with the XML parser, rather than the HTML parser.

Edit: Just realised this:

```
<START:organization>..<END>
```

There's a couple of problems here. First, the start and end tags don't match. If the opening tag is '´`then it should be terminated by``. Second, using a colon in the node name has a certain meaning in XML - Namely that the first part is a namespace and the second part the node name. In this case, you should either use a tag named "organisation", or have it in an attribute. The first would probably make the most sense. So:

```
<organization>..</organization>
```

If you can't change this, then you can't use an XML/HTML parser, as it isn't valid XML nor HTML.